# Show data of today and one week earlier in one row. Is it possible in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Table example

```
id  |   name    |   value   |   date
--------------------------------------------
1   |   abc     |   20      |   2018-01-26
1   |   abc     |   24      |   2018-01-27
1   |   abc     |   25      |   2018-01-28
1   |   abc     |   30      |   2018-01-29
```

I know how to fetch data from 28th Jan or today. But I need some way to show values of two dates in two columns. Is it possible in one mysql query?

**Like this**

```
name    |   value_today |   value_pre
---------------------------------------
abc     |   30          |   25
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more how 30 and 25 is coming as result?

Comment: you can use another select to get the value of last week.

Comment: I have huge data. So another query means more time will be taken by the queries. I want to know if there is any way to do this in one query @Nhial

Comment: That sound likes you need to redesign the application, because you can split the table and store last week values in another table, then you can do joins.

Comment: Yes. 30 means the value of 2017-01-29 and 25 can be the value of 28th of any day. I want just an extra column with my MySQL results which contain another date's value along with today's value. @Mittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `case`. This query returns the today's value and previous date value:

```
SELECT 
id, name, 
 Sum(Case When date = CURDATE()
         Then value Else 0 End) TodaySum,
 Sum(Case When (date = CURDATE()-1)
         Then value Else 0 End) PreviousSum
FROM tbl1
group by id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hypothetical query that would do it.

```
SELECT t1.value AS value_today,(SELECT t2.value FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.date=2018-01-29 ) AS value_pre 
FROM table AS t1 WHERE t1.date=2018-01-28
```